# problem to retrieve data from form/select

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a little problem to retrieve data from a form :
I send the data in POST to my file *cibe.php*
the form is composed of a select of which I would like to recover the data:

```html
<form method="post" action="add_bdd.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact100-form validate-form">
  <select class="js-select2 select_state" name="_state[1]">
    <option value="europe">Europe</option>
    <option value="allemagne">Allemagne</option>
    <option value="autriche">Autriche</option>
    <option value="belgique">Belgique</option>
    <option value="chypre">Chypre</option>
    <option value="croatie">Croatie</option>
    <option value="danemark">Danemark</option>
    <option value="espagne">Espagne</option>
    <option value="estonie">Estonie</option>
    <option value="finlande">Finlande</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="irlande">Irlande</option>
    <option value="islande">Islande</option>
    <option value="italie">Italie</option>
    <option value="lituanie">Lituanie</option>
    <option value="luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="norvege">Norvege</option>
    <option value="pays-bas">Pays-Bas</option>
    <option value="republique-tcheque">Republique-Tcheque</option>
    <option value="slovenie">Slovénie</option>
    <option value="suede">Suède</option>
    <option value="suisse">Suisse</option>
  </select>
  <!-- other inputs -->
</form>
```

the problem is the following if I do this I can not get the data from _state [1]

```
<p><strong>service 1 =<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["_techno"]); ?></strong></p>
```

Comment: i have try too 
```php
    <p><strong>service 1 =<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["_techno[1]"]); ?></strong></p>

```

Comment: why you are trying to get the value with `_techno[1]`, your select tag have name `_state[1]`?

Comment: yes, excuse me, there are both, it comes back to the same

Comment: ```Html
<select class="js-select2 select_techno" name="_techno[1]">
           <option value="Solaire">Solaire</option>
           <option value="Hydro">Hydraulique</option>
           <option value="Eolien">Eolienne</option>
           <option value="BioMasse">BioMasse</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: the form is too big but the declaration is :
```html
    <form method="post" action="add_bdd.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact100-form validate-form">

```

Comment: Looks like you are confused with the `name`. In Select, you are defining the name as `_state[1]` and in PHP, you are trying to get `$_POST['_techno']`. You need to use the same name as defined in HTML.

Comment: To debug this, try `var_dump($_POST);`